# Rails 2.3.8 in IIS6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iis, iis-6

My server is running on IIS6, and i having trouble with setting up rails with IIS.

1st) is there any posible way to run Nginx on a domain:80 while therest:80 are running on IIS?

2nd) How should I make it work on IIS6 because despite follow the instruction here http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/02/18/10-steps-to-get-Ruby-on-Rails-running-on-Windows-with-IIS-FastCGI.aspx , I just can't get it to work. Result is a "Directory Listing Denied" error.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options if IIS is a necessity:

- I would propose to investigate IronRuby, which integrates better with IIS.
- Otherwise I would run nginx on another port, and let IIS forward a certain path to that instance.

Personally i have deployed on windows, but just used apache and a mongrel-cluster. 
When i was looking at it, IronRuby did not yet offer the integration with IIS; and i found very little information concerning how to configure IIS to do what i wanted.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

1.) No, there is no way you can have 2 different programs running on the same port, it's simply not possible. But you can change either one to run on different ports (for example, if you want Nginx as the "primary", give it port 80 and change IIS to 8080 or whatever). Or, as @nathanvda mentions, you could use a redirect script from one to send certain paths to the other (port & path).

2.) The "Directory Listing Denied" error suggests that either (a) you haven't set the directory permissions correctly in IIS--be sure that Execute Permissions allow scripts in all your Ruby directories, or (b) the handler mapping which directs files to use the Ruby interpreter via FastCGI is not set correctly--double-check step 8 or check other sources for more details on this setting.